# Using bump node to achieve what displacement (on Bump mode) could do

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

Hi, so we have bump node to achieve bumpyness of a surface and we also have displacement socket on (bump mode) that could achieve bumpyness too. But in screenshot above, i found out that displacement (on bump mode, no true displacement) makes a better result while using bump node, it's result is not as that good than displacement can do..
So, how to achieve similiar result like displacement socket using bump node? Is it possible?
My intention is because i need two different bump on 2 principled bsdf mixed together with an image as mask..
Thanks in advance guys
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to combine displacements you can do so with the *MixRGB* node here is a basic node tree combining a cobblestone and bricks displacement map together, although not using the bump node you can try using your bump maps in the image textures:

[image]

This produced the result:

[image]

Note that the MixRGB node in the diffuse color socket was not necessary, only in the displacement socket. This setup can be used regardless of the other shaders, specular workflow or using the principled shaders will not affect it as the displacement socket is separate from the other material outputs. So for your situation of using two principled shaders together this is a time and effort efficient way of getting nice and detailed combined displacement results from two materials.